# Tiny MCE wether to use relative url

Tags: php, tinymce-4

I am using tiny MCE for the product description. Now the website is in development server and client had already start to upload the real product content. When image are inserted in  tiny MCE, I found the images are saved in relative URL like

```
 ../../tinymce/file_manager/source/Samsung%20Smart%20TV%20Features/Quad%20Core.jpg?1471847855279
```

But its not displaying in webpage. I am using codeigniter. My problem are:

- Relative url are not working. So as to make it work I need to go three step folder backward. So the valid image path would be: 
     ../../../../../tinymce/and so on. How do I configure the relative url to mentioned url.
- Another problem I edited the path from database and when editing the product then I see there is no relative path as I have edited directly from database.

How to get rid of this problem. Thank you.

Comment: you can use this config. `convert_urls : false, relative_urls : false,`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read here `URL Conversion`

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/demo/url-conversion/